# Avoid drop once that dropped items count reach some limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using Jquery UI Draggable.
I'm trying to avoid items from be dropped once that the div which will receive that items reach a limit. As you can see below, here is my code.

```
 $( "#grid-list" ).droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
          count = 0;
          $("#grid-list").find("li").each(function () {
            count++;

            if(count > $("#grid-list").data("albumlist")){
              alert("limit reached");
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/r1Lnxby9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try removing `ondragstart="drag(event)"` , `draggable="true"` from `html` , `drag` not appear defined at `js`; setting `tolerance:"touch"` at `.droppable()` options ; substituting `$("> li", this).length` for `count` , `$("#grid-list").each()` ; `>=` for `>` if expected result is `1` element maximum within `.droppable()` element ; call `event.preventDefault()` , `event.stopPropagation()` within `over` event

```js
  $("#list-albuns, #grid-list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#grid-list").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    over: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("> li", this).length >= $(this).data("albumlist")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert("limit");
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<ul id="list-albuns" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
  <li id="0" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="0">
    <img id="dragimg0" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/51552793.png" alt="Appetite for Destruction">
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="2">
    <img id="dragimg2" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/97176319.png" alt="Use Your Illusion II">
  </li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="3">
    <img id="dragimg3" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/89710469.png" alt="40 Seasons - The Best Of Skid Row">
  </li>
  <li id="5" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="5">
    <img id="dragimg5" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/56005467.jpg" alt="Danger Danger">
  </li>
  <li id="6" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="6">
    <img id="dragimg6" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/85595741.jpg" alt="Screw It [Italy Bonus Tracks]">
  </li>
  <li id="7" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId[]" value="7">
    <img id="dragimg7" height="126" width="126" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90791541.jpg" alt="Detonator">
  </li>
</ul>Drop Here:
<ul id="grid-list" data-albumlist="1" class="connectedSortable" style="width:500px; height:200px;display:block; border:2px solid black;"></ul>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r1Lnxby9/2/

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually i need to "return false" then send item back to his original place. My current code do the alert, but that item is dropped anyway.

Comment: @DênisFernandes Yes. `js` at answer attempts to convey defining `count` outside of `.droppable()` , evaluate , increment `count` at a `.droppable`  `event` hander , prevent `drop` event within `event` handler

Comment: Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/r1Lnxby9/

So how prevent from being dropped  using event handler?

Thanks, regards!